# WorkerLost Error: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, celery, nltk

I tried to find the answer here but I didn't get the answer what I want.
So I'm posting the question.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopset, use_idf=True, ngram_range=[1, 4])
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document_list)
lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2, n_iter=10)
lsa.fit(X)


results = []
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

I'm running the code like above for some reason.
when I run above code in python directly, that works fine and I can get result exaclty.
but When I run above code inside celery (I'm using celery with flask), I'm getting following error.
Any suggestion is helpful for me.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty similar to [this issue on celery's github](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2964).

Comment: I've already checked that issue. but I didn't get the solution.

Comment: @Fian Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?
I'm not much familiar with sklearn so I can't imagine what I need to do for this.

Comment: As it was stated in github issue, seems like libraries you use (usually machine learning and statistical libs are written in C/C++ and have python interfaces) are not thread safe and can't be used in two separate threads. Try using multiprocess instead of multithreading in your app/celery.

Comment: any example or link for that? that will help me a lot.

Comment: As I suppose, Celery uses by [default Prefork worker type](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-pool) (which is as I suppose uses threads), but if you somehow (I'm pretty sure it's possible and quite trivial) change worker type to process-based that might work. Also, revise documentation on libs you use if it's explicitly mentioned that they're not thread-safe — maybe there would be a solution how to make a workaround.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187920/discussion-between-kyl-and-fian).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by putting all of the imports for these libraries inside the task function instead of at the top of the file.

```
@celery.task
def reduce_features(cik):
     from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
     # your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. However, the error SIGSEGV used to happen only once per worker, per task. so if I had 3 tasks, and 2 workers GREEN & BLUE. Each first task run of the 2 tasks on GREEN used to fail, and also on BLUE.
I tried:

- There is NO need to create a retry handler for `WorkerLostError`
- Importing inside functions didn't help

What worked:

- while launching Celery worker using the option `-p` ([Docs Link](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/index.html#overview-of-concurrency-options))
- I recommend to use `gevent`